# Terminate Java Thread on Key

Tags: java, multithreading, keylistener

I am writing a java swing program that involves using a thread to update the UI,

The `run` function in the thread contains a while loop and a sleep timer,

I want to either terminate the while loop or the thread itself when the user presses for example `ctrl+c`. The thread includes a sleep command, I don't want the user to have to hold down `ctrl+c` to terminate, I just want to be able to use those keys once.

How is this possible?

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    .......//Code to set up window

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(user has not terminated the program with ctrl+c){
                //Do Something
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                }
            }
        }

    };

    .......//Code to start thread
}
```

Comment: use a `keyListener` and in the action Either `interrupt the thread` or make the `condition inside while as false` !

Comment: It *seems* like you're asking about ctrl+c being entered on the terminal where the program is being run from? That's going to terminate the JVM and all your threads. If you mean you actually want the user to be able to hit ctrl+c while your GUI app has focus .. then the answers being posted should help.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, threads are terminated cooperatively. This means that it requires modifying both the code inside the thread as well as the code outside the thread. Outside the thread, you can signal that the thread should prepare to shutdown by using the [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) method. Inside the thread, you should check [Thread.interrupted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) to test for interruption (and break from the loop if that is the case). You should also modify your exception handler; the interrupted exception is thrown when Thread.interrupt() was called while the thread was sleeping, so you should modify the content of that handler to break from the loop.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
class A{
Thread r1Thread;
public static boolean isCtrlCPressed = false;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    .......//Code to set up window
    MyRun r1 = new MyRun();
    r1Thread = new Thread(r1);
    r1Thread.start();
   }

   public void someMethodThatDetectCtrlC(){
      r1Thread.interrupt();
   }

}
```

Your Thread

```
       class MyRun implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   try{

                        Thread.sleep(5000);

                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you pointed out issue. I have changed the code i think it should work

Answer (score -1):

Make a boolean called "running"

Change your while loop to while(running)

Add a keylistener, make it listen for Ctrl + C.

If it hears Ctrl + C, set running = false.

Since running == false, the while loop will then stop.

Comment: And how does that solve the problem of the thread currently sleeping?